# PhpStorm debugger with a docker container, nginx in reverse proxy and https

Tags: docker, nginx, https, phpstorm, xdebug

I need some help in order to configure PhpStorm debugger with a particular development configuration.
On my pc (192.168.1.23) I have the source code of a PHP project, a dbms and an instance of nginx as reverse proxy. Nginx is configured in order to send all the traffic to a docker container:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name www.mysite.local;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/;

        # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        location ~ \.php$ {
               include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
               fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        }

        location / {
                index index.html  index.php;
        }

}

upstream backend  {
  # configuration in order to use apache inside docker container
  server 172.17.0.2:80;
}
```

The docker container (172.17.0.2) has been created with:

```
docker run -dP --add-host=db.local:172.17.0.1 \
      -e remote_connect_back_xdbg=1 \
      -e remote_host_xdbg='192.168.1.23' \
      -v /opt/live:/opt/live \
      --name local_php_apache_container local_php_apache_image
```

So Docker mounts my project (located at /opt/live) inside /opt/live of the container. The container is a Debian 9 with PHP 5.3 + Apache2.
And it is started automatically at the boot of the pc with this command:

```
docker exec -it local_php_apache_container /bin/bash
```

Inside the docker container, the xdebug configuration in php.ini is:

```
[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_connect_back=${remote_connect_back_xdbg}
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=10123
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_log=/stackdriver/log/xdebug.log
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_host=${remote_host_xdbg}
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
```

The idkey is netbeans-xdebug because with netbeans, the debugger works properly (https://www.mysite.local/index.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug, https with a local untrusted certificate)

[image]

[image]

But I have a lot of problems with PHPStorm and the position of PHP interpreter, both with PHP Build-in Web Server and with PHP Remote Debug configuration...
Any suggestions?

Comment: 1) Try to explicitly set `xdebug.remote_connect_back=0` & `xdebug.remote_host=<your_host_as_seen_by_docker>`. 2) you're asking about PhpStorm config & attaching netbeans screenshots? Please attach screenshots of File | Settings | Languages & Frameworks | PHP | Debug; File | Settings | Languages & Frameworks | PHP | Servers. 3) try a debugging session again with PhpStorm again & attach your `/stackdriver/log/xdebug.log`

Comment: If `xdebug.remote_connect_back=1` (active) then `xdebug.remote_host` is ignored completely (by Xdebug itself). The rest  -- what Ástþór have said.

Comment: i) I added netbeans screenshots just to show a working configuration with another ide   ii) the `/stackdriver/log/xdebug.log` is always empty in my tests with phpstorm  iii) here a pdf with some screenshots from the phpstorm configuration: [remote_debug_phpstorm_test.pdf](https://docdro.id/ZOlF1cc)